# Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 7 not displaying site

Tags: internet-explorer, windows-7, internet-explorer-11, ieframe.dll

The site http://broadbandandphones.co.uk works fine basically everywhere (FF, Chrome, Safari, IE, Edge etc...) however for some reason IE11 on Windows 7 will not render the site instead throwing a delightfully vague ieframe.dll/acr_error.

The behaviour is the same on 3 separate Widows 7 machines all running on different networks so I'm pretty confident it's not a simple case of resetting permissions/IE settings on the local machine, although I have tried that - with no joy!

To make things even more fun the problem seem to be somewhat sporadic, certain pages might load fine one minute but then bottom-out the next.

I'm pretty much stuck and was wondering if anyone had experience similar behaviour? Or point me in the direction of how to debug whatever is causing the problem.

Comment: Googling around with this search: https://www.google.com/search?q=ieframe.dll%2Facr_error&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 ... it seems that there could be several causes/reasons for that error. Users at one Microsoft site have claimed success disabling all add-ons: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie8-windows_other/resieframedllacrerrorhtm/961b52cc-b113-4af0-b49a-a1c217c770c5 ... yet, another found that the video driver was the culprit:  https://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=149338.0 ... if I get to a Windows 7 machine later today, I'll give your link a try and post another comment.

Comment: Ok, I was able to try your link on a Windows 7 system with IE 11, version 11.0.9600.18697, and it loaded just fine, no error(s) for me.

Comment: ...also, in the About dialog info., there is an entry that shows:  Update Versions: 11.0.43 (KB4021558), in case this might relevant. There was a Windows security update to IE 11, and after it updated, I checked the link again, and the site still loaded OK afterwards -- no error(s).